# Can the Wizard's "Spell Blending" Arcane Thesis be used to convert spell slots of one tradition to another?

Tags: spells, wizard, spell-slots, pathfinder-2e

For example, if a Wizard takes [Cleric Multiclass Archetype feats](https://2e.aonprd.com/Archetypes.aspx?ID=5) to gain Cleric spell slots, can he use the [Spell Blending](https://2e.aonprd.com/ArcaneThesis.aspx?ID=3) Arcane Thesis to transform the Cleric spell slots into Wizard spell slots of a higher level? Conversely, can he transform his Wizard spell slots into Cleric spell slots of a higher level?

Answer (score 1):

### Strict RAW, the Spell Blending ability applies to all spellcasting a character has.

That is to say, you would be able to convert Cleric spell slots to higher level Cleric spell slots (that you have access to) or Wizard spell slots and vice-versa. The ability is somewhat vague in it's description, but everywhere else in the PHB is pretty explicit. The relevant text

> When you make your daily preparations, you can trade two spell slots of the same level for a bonus spell slot of up to 2 levels higher than the traded spell slots. You can exchange as many spell slots as you have available.

does not restrict you to "Wizard spell preparation" or "two Arcane spell slots... bonus Arcane spell slot" or anything of the like. As an example of explicit test, just look at the next Arcane Thesis, [Spell Substitution](https://2e.aonprd.com/ArcaneThesis.aspx?ID=4) (PHB p. 206)

> You can spend 10 minutes to empty one of your prepared spell slots and prepare a different spell from your spellbook in its place.

Sidenote: regardless of which spell slots you gain/lose, you are still restricted by the other portion of the Spell Blending feature

> Bonus spell slots must be of a level you can normally cast, and each bonus spell slot must be of a different spell level.

So you could not gain more advanced Cleric spellcasting than normally available, nor gain a 3rd level Wizard and a 3rd level Cleric spell on the same day.

---

Make sure to check with your GM. There is a portion of the Class Features description itself that some GM's will interpret that specialized class features are intended to work only for their class, and others may not feel like it fits Lore that you would be able to Blend the different traditions. The flavor text of Spell Blending supports this use of the ability, though.

From the [Class Features](https://2e.aonprd.com/Rules.aspx?ID=141) section:

> All classes include the class features detailed below, and each class also gets **special class features specific to it**.

And the Spell Blending "it was intended to work" text

> You theorize that spell slots are a shorthand for an underlying **energy that powers all spellcasting**